# How to set maximum value for an integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, max

How do I set a maximum limit for an integer in Python I tried using an if statement and it works but i thought there might be a better way to do that

code i'm using to do that works fine

```py
f = 100
f = f + 15
if(f > 100):
    f = 100
print(f)
```

also tried to use a function but it gives an error after a while

```py
def limit(f):
    if(f > 100):
     return 100
```

calling function

```py
f = limit(f)
```

like writing two lines of code everytime time f changes is not a big deal but it would be better if there was a shorter way

Comment: Use `min`: `return min(f, 100)`

Comment: where should I write this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be done with the built-in min function

```
f = min(f, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line as

```
def limit(x):
    return x if x <= 100 else 100
```

OR in more pythonic way

```
def limit(x, max_val=100):
    return x if x <= max_val else max_val
```

Comment: Use the built-ins `max` as a parameter name, is not a good idea, should try to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the remark changed it to `max_val`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a function, there is already a function which does what you want:

```
>>> a = 85
>>> limit = 100
>>> a = min(limit, a + 10)
>>> a
95
>>> a = min(limit, a + 10)
>>> a
100
```

Comment: Spot on. Just for the reference, since we don't really know what's expected maximum here, it could mention there is `math.inf`?